# Formula / macro

Tags: excel, formula, vba

Not sure if this is going to be possible but I want to create a reporting feature on a spreadsheet I have created.

I need to look for a subject in column b then look for a word in that row and the for it to give me the name from the cell above. Example:

Look for 'who's who', in column B then look for 'TBR' in that row, and then I want the name from cell C6.

Any help would be great. Any questions just let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Terrible tittle, try to explain you problem in the title

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need something like this (adjust according to your data). This formula:

1. Looks for `"c"` in column `A:A` - result is row `4:4`.
2. Looks for `"r"` in row `4:4` - result is `D4`.
3. Looks for value in row `1:1` above `D4` (i.e. `D1`) - result is `"cold"`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I think it may work, however the data is on a different sheet than where I want the formula to be. Also where you have the 1:1 in the formula I'm not sure what that part is relating to. Could you explain a little more? Thanks for this it's really appreciated.

Comment: Actually looking at it now, I'm not sure this will work as I need it to give me more than one answer.- I need it to look in column b to find 'a' then look along that row to find 'TBR' (there will be more that one) then give me all the names from above each column. Do you think this will be possible?

Comment: `1:1` means "the whole row 1". If you need multiple results in single cell that won't be possible without VBA.